# App Inventor IDE: Build Error

Tags: android, app-inventor, apk

I am developing an Android application through the App Inventor IDE, but at the moment of building an apk package I get the following error:

Could not fetch URL: http://ec2-175-41-202-13.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9990/buildserver/build-all-from-zip-async?uname=pasquale.puzio%40gmail.com&mercurialBuildId=16491dac07c2%2B+61%2B&callback=http%3A%2F%2Fjoners-inventor.appspot.com%2Fode2%2Freceivebuild%2Fd72c6vqyvzg2w27i6vgxrbvgewk7dp2d5eysm7cxh0qoembjk3vdeg91yt96egv9lblej7880gyehs8oiixj26utyc7a32yxzdh9tf5admmmvp2jg0vvyi08ubxp0jnuxts0uri2gv%2Fbuild%2FAndroid

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running your own App Inventor server from jars or using someone else's server?

Comment: Solved!! I am using the official App Inventor app provided by MIT and all works fine.